# Thumbnails and picking picasa images from gallery on ICS

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, picasa

I'm having a hard time getting Thumbnails.getThumbnail to work with picasa photos on a Nexus S running ICS. Everything else seems to work including getting the original image from picasa and displaying it, but the getThumbnail doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the following errors when attempting to use it:

```
E/MiniThumbFile( 1852): Got exception when reading magic, id = 5745625138093120418, disk full or mount read-only? class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
W/MediaProvider(  540): original media doesn't exist or it's canceled.
```

The disk is not full, it is read-write, the app has external storage write permissions, and the picture does indeed exist on picasa (I can view it through the android Gallery app).

The same code works fine on Android 2.3, but it follows a slightly different path, as 2.3 seems to download a copy of the photo and hand you the actual local file:// uri to the newly downloaded image, rather than hand you a content:// uri.

This is the main meat of the code in question:

```
  public void addImage(Uri uri, boolean local)
  {
     ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
     Uri actualUri = uri;

     Log.d(TAG, "addImage: original uri: " + uri.toString());

     if(local) {
        try {
           List<String> uriPath = uri.getPathSegments();
           String contentUri = Media.insertImage(resolver, uri.getPath(), uriPath.get(uriPath.size()-1), new String());
           actualUri = Uri.parse(contentUri);
        }
        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: ");
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     Log.d(TAG, "addImage: actual uri: " + actualUri.toString());

     List<String> uriPath = actualUri.getPathSegments();
     long imageId = Long.parseLong(uriPath.get(uriPath.size() -1));

     Bitmap thumb = Thumbnails.getThumbnail(resolver, imageId, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
     if(thumb == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get thumbnail for our image.");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get thumbnail for image. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
     }

     uris.add(uri);
     bmps.add(thumb);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

That method is called when ever a new photo is added to the application's "collection" of photos. When its known to be a local image (ie: if a photo was taken from inside the app, or onActivityResult's data argument is null), the local parameter is set to true and I attempt to get a content:// uri back from the media content provider so we can get a valid image id to pass to Thumbnails.getThumbnail. That code works fine for images gotten from the Camera app (via startActivityForResult), as well as images from the gallery that are stored locally on the device.

I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: The best answer for me : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8936697/994324<br/>
It's working for all cases (actually): picasa, and local pictures, and it's far more clean.

Comment: @Tomasu.. Thank you so much dear I Got solved my problem with quesion's sample code. anyway I would like to share my code with you in answer. Hope it will help other too. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#media_group

If you are having a hard time in android getting to the thumbnails, note the above link and 
api and the media:group/media:thumbnail tag in the atom feed. Thats the parent element or the container of the thumbnails refered to [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592633/php-picasa-api-show-large-image/10611532#10611532)

So, in order to process thumbs in android, if you can structure your code to actually use the api ( picasa feeds / photos / media:group etc. ) you may have fewer bugs issues like the present one.

Sample google/ android / picasa [code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/tags/2.2.1-alpha/sample/picasa/picasa-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/data/sample/picasa/PicasaAtomAndroidSample.java)

[api ref](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

[another api ref](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm not particularly interested in picasa photos to begin with in the app I'm currently working on, but I would like the current functionality to "just work". Sadly it seems the Thumbnail class just doesn't know how to make thumbnails from picasa images. I've written a bunch of custom image grabbing, scaling and thumbnailing (the thumbnailing code is really just the image scaling code but special cased to thumbnail size) code that properly handles showing "full sized" photos (scaled to fit within max texture size) and thumbnails with the proper orientation.

Comment: Basically what I've done is fetch the image raw from picasa and then thumbnail that. Seems to work just fine. And since by default I use the ContentResolver class, that bit is handled automatically.

Comment: sounds good.as always, you can create your own or adapt and reuse modules done by others.

Comment: I do wish they didn't change how the picasa stuff worked in ICS. Or at least made it so the Thumbnail class would work with it. With 2.3, picasa images are downloaded to a local file, and it passes you that. And in ICS, you get a content:// uri which has an id, but one that doesn't work with Thumbnail. It looks like it's /supposed/ to work. It just doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it was an import/package problem.

Make sure to use the correct Thumbnail class. There are two. One for Video and one for Images.

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails
```